# XSS issue on a clicking hyperink in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have a page with hyperlink with below html code.

```
<a id="More Details" name="More Details" href="javascript:processing_win0(0,3000); void window.open(method1('xyz.com?param1=%27+alert(123)+%27),'','');"  tabindex="1">More Details</a>
```

In above href, though "param1" is properly encoded the browser is throwing a alert popup on clicking the hyperlink "More Details".

what is wrong with this html element?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding is not correct. `param1` is inside the xyz url, but the JavaScript code is in the href url of the `a` tag as well. So there are two levels of encoding required, one for the inner url, and one for the outer one.

A `'` symbol becomes `%27` when encoded for the inner url, and then `%2527` for the other.

This can be solved by not putting so much code into the `href` attribute, and instead putting it into another function within a JavaScript file.

Comment: Still I didn't get your point, why we need to need 2 level encoding here. Basically encoding is required for the URL and that is already done and assigned to 'href' attribute. May be I didn't understand the concept clearly